# How do i get the attribute value in array form in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to get attribute style value in array form because there are more than one class `.pro-color-active`.

**Here is my code**

```
cy.get('#cdk-accordion-child-0').find('.pro-color-active').invoke('attr','style').then((text2)=> {
     Array.from(text2)
     cy.log('text2: ' + text2)
})
```

It gives me only one value of style attribute while there is 3 style attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.each()` to loop over all the elements and log the values:

```js
cy.get('#cdk-accordion-child-0').find('.pro-color-active').each(($ele, index) => {
  //Prints value one by one
  cy.log('Value of element ' + index + ": " + $ele.attr('style'))
})
```